# Angular: How to cache the response of an api call inside service component?

Tags: angular, api, session-storage

I want to cache the response of api call inside the service component so that it could be accessed by the other components to fetch the data. How it can be done? Which concept best suites this?

Comment: You want to share the response of the http call (i.e. an observable) between differents components right ? What is your use case ? To me, it looks like you want a __cache__. You could implement your own cache logic (it requires a good understanding) or you could [use ngx-cacheable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cacheable)

Comment: [I googled this article for you](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider converting your application into a Progressive Web Application (PWA) by adding a service. A starting point to this will be using this schematic.

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

After having a service worker the cli will generate a file called ngsw-config.json. Here you can cache your static assets and also api calls in which you are referring to here. To learn more about this go to this url.

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cache the response of a GET Request for performance reasons or to deliver the data even when offline, then as Dilshan said, you can add the service worker module with the add schematics.

Here a [full step by step demo](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular) to learn how to create a PWA with Angular.

Then in the ngsw-config.json file you target the API Request in the `dataGroups` array:

```
"dataGroups": [{
    "name": "jokes-cache",
    "urls": [ "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/" ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "performance",
      "maxSize": 5,
      "maxAge": "1d"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "stocks-cache",
    "urls": [ "https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock" ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 10,
      "maxAge": "1d",
      "timeout": "10s"
    }
  }]
```

**BUT** if you want to store some data and share it among other components, then you can user a `RxJs ReplaySubject` for that. The code below executes a `GET` and then caches the result locally. So following calls will not trigger new requests, but the cached data will be returned instead.

```
    getUsers(reload: boolean = false): Observable<User[]> {
    if (!this.cache$ || reload) {
      if (!this.cache$) {
        this.cache$ = new ReplaySubject<User[]>(1);
      }

      this.getUsersFromServer()
        .pipe(
          map(result => result.map(f => new User(f)))
        )
        .subscribe(
          users => this.cachedInvoices$.next(users)
        );
    }

    return this.cache$.asObservable();
  }
```